# How to find the same folder on different machine in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, directory-structure

I have the following folder structure:

```
demo
├── module1
│   └── demo.py     
├── module2
    └── somefile.txt
```

I want to be able to find `somefile.txt` from `demo.py` no matter from where `demo.py` is launched.

What I've tried is using os.walk() in the following way:

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk("module2", False):
        for file in files:
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
```

This will only be able to find it if I launch `demo.py` while I am in the `demo/` folder. If I am launching it from `demo/module1` then it prints nothing.

My final goal is to be able to run this piece of code on any machine with Python no matter where the root `demo/` folder is placed in the system.

Comment: if `demo/` can be in any place and `demo.py` also can be in any place then you would have to check all folders in system.

Comment: maybe inside `demo.py` you should get `__file__` to get its location and use it to get path to `module2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular method to get correct location of running code

```
import os

FOLDER = os.path.abspath(os.path.basename(__file__))
```

If you use it in `demo.py` then you should always get `/full/path/to/module1`

And then you can do

```
path = os.path.join(FOLDER, "..", "module2", "somefile.txt")
```

to get full path to `somefile.txt`

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
import os
somefile_path = os.path.basename(os.getcwd()) + 'module2\\' + 'somefile.txt'
```